# How can I turn off line length violations for an entire project when using SwiftLint

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftlint

I just installed swiftlint and after running it, a lot of my warnings and errors are line length violations. I don't particularly care for how long my lines are. I'm just using SwiftLint to remove more important errors.

Now to be clear, I know I can use a comment like `// swiftlint:disable` to disable it in one file but I want to disable it across my project. I did have some trouble with the configuration file as well, if you can give me the code for the config, that works too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `line_length` rule into the `disabled_rules` section of your `.swiftlint.yml` config file

```
disabled_rules:
  - line_length
```

Comment: Where i can find this file .swiftlint.yml? I have installed through brew commands, will this in be my project folder as hidden?

Comment: You create this file yourself. It's usually placed in each of your projects respective root folder.

Comment: Is this just enough and add rules there? Is there any other configuration? How system will analyze the rules?

Comment: Please see https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#configuration

Comment: i have done but not able to exclude pods directory, do you have any idea?

Comment: I suggest you ask this as a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).